# Join Firebase tables with listeners?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it feasible to join two or more Firebase tables together using `child_added`, `child_changed`, and `child_removed` listeners?

For instance, imagine that you have two tables. One contains basic information about users, and the other relates users to roles.

**Users**

```
{
    "1":
    {
        "forename": "Joe",
        "surname": "Bloggs"
    },
    "2":
    {
        "forename": "Jane",
        "surname": "Doe"
    },
    "3":
    {
        "forename": "Luke",
        "surname": "Skywalker"
    }
}
```

**User-Role Relations**

```
{
    "a":
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "roleId": 2
    },
    "b":
    {
        "userId": 2,
        "roleId": 2
    },
    "c":
    {
        "userId": 3,
        "roleId": 4
    }
}
```

**Join**

If you wanted to retrieve all users with role `2`, you could write a normal Firebase query using `orderByChild` and `equalTo` with `roleId`. For each `child_added` for this, you could then also listen to `child_added` for each related user, using `orderByChild`. Then, the values from both documents could be rolled into a single object, used by your app. It might look something like the following.

**Code**

```
function join(initial, joins, callback)
{
    const result = [];
    initial.query.on
    (
        'child_added',
        function(initialSnapshot)
        {
            const initialChild = initialSnapshot.val();
            let initialResult = initialChild;
            const resultIndex = result.push(initialResult) - 1;
            joins.forEach
            (
                function(join)
                {
                    const delay = Math.floor(resultIndex / LISTENER_BATCH_LENGTH);
                    setTimeout
                    (
                        function()
                        {
                            join.query(initialChild);
                            let joinResultPrevious = null;
                            const addedCallback = joinQuery.on
                            (
                                'child_added',
                                function(joinSnapshot)
                                {
                                    const joinChild = joinSnapshot.val();
                                    const joinResult = joinChild;
                                    joinResultPrevious = joinResult;
                                    initialResult = Object.assign(initialResult, joinResult);
                                    callback(result);
                                }
                            );
                            joinQuery.on
                            (
                                'child_changed',
                                function(joinSnapshot)
                                {
                                    const joinChild = joinSnapshot.val();
                                    const joinResult = joinChild;
                                    const deletedProperties = getMissingProperties(joinResult, joinResultPrevious);
                                    deletedProperties.forEach
                                    (
                                        function(property)
                                        {
                                            delete initialResult[property];
                                        }
                                    );
                                    initialResult = Object.assign(initialResult, joinResult);
                                    joinResultPrevious = joinResult;
                                    callback(result);
                                }
                            );
                            joinQuery.on
                            (
                                'child_removed',
                                function()
                                {
                                    result.splice(resultIndex, 1);
                                    callback(result);
                                }
                            );
                        },
                        delay
                    );
                );
            }
        );
    };
```

**Performance**

The trouble is, I've tried out this function, and while it works, it works very slowly. I tested with approximately 2,100 user documents, and their corresponding user-role relation documents. Using Chrome's profiling tools, most of the CPU time seems to be spent on some part of Firebase. I don't know which part this is, as the function names seem to be obfuscated, with one of the expensive functions being labelled `Qa`. Perhaps a browser simply cannot be expected to do this much work. However, I did wonder whether it might be that Firebase is making thousands of independent requests, when it might be much less expensive were it to bulk requests together. Either way, it would be useful to know whether joining tables in this way is feasible, given the apparent performance issues.

**Update**

I seem to have largely resolved the performance issues. They seemed to stem from Firebase somehow locking up the browser thread. Introducing a batched delay with `setTimeout` for the join listeners seems to release control to other processes, including the DOM, which provides for a much smoother and faster user experience.

Comment: You're using `joinQuery.on` If you tried with >2000 user documents, you've kept >2000 active listeners. That's a bit much. i doubt it's the number of requests, although my first action would be to find a way to only load the data that you're showing to the user.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your thoughts. I am aware that the function entails that a large number of listeners will be created, probably over 6,000 in total given that each relation uses the three `child_*` events. But I don't understand how this many listeners is as expensive as it is. Could you please explain? I imagine it depends on the internals of Firebase.

Comment: Sorry, that's a bit beyond something I can address here on Stack Overflow. If you're interested in the internals of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, I recommend you check out its source on https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk. My usual recommendation is to limit the listeners to the data you're actively showing to your user, and potentially duplicate data when the number of listeners becomes unwieldy.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the suggestions. I have taken a look at the Firebase source, but finding the responsible components is a little difficult. In any case, I have updated my original question with a potential solution involving `setTimeout`. Essentially, Firebase seemed to be locking up the browser thread, which was resolved by encapsulating the join listeners within a very brief `setTimeout`, which releases the thread to other processes.

Comment: Ouch, that sounds like something that shouldn't be needed. Can you share the minimal code that shows your workaround? I'd like to see what you do in the callback, although I'm afraid it indeed won't be anything suspicious.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Indeed, this should be handled by Firebase internally. Unfortunately, it does not seem to be. I have updated my original question with the code including the `setTimeout`. If you're referring to the `callback(result)` call, during my performance tests and workaround efforts, I commented out that line so that I could focus on resolving the listener problem, without anything complicating matters. Besides workarounds like `setTimeout` and Web Workers, the single-threaded nature of browsers can sometimes bite you, and this seems to be one such case.